# How to set button selection color along with rounded corners in android?

Tags: android, background-color, rounded-corners, android-button

I want to set a rounded corner for a button in android along with changing the button color on  when selected. I am doing the following things.

drawable/push_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/green"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@color/green"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false"  android:drawable="@color/green"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/push_button_background"/>         
</selector>
```

drawable/push_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >
    <solid android:color="#3F4040"/>
    <corners 
    android:radius="7dp"
    />
</shape>
```

and in code, I am using

```
android:background="@drawable/push_button"
```

Here, the problem is, button colors are setting properly when selected & deselected. But, rounded corners are not working.

How to do that?
If I use

```
android:background="@drawable/push_button_background"
```

then, rounded corners are working but the button color change on selection is not working

How to implement this?

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400852/round-cornered-button-with-background-color-in-android) link. Even then no help!!

Comment: you may need to define another few `drawables` with your desired colors and all with radius, and change `@color/color` to your defined `drawables`.

Comment: @Aprian.. can you please elaborate bit more? I am a newbie to android!! can you give some sample?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I have found answer for my question with few trial & error attempts.

Here is the solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    

 <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape  >
    <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
    <corners 
    android:radius="7dp"/>
    </shape>
 </item>

 <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
    <corners 
    android:radius="7dp"/>
    </shape>
 </item>

 <item android:state_focused="false" >
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <corners 
    android:radius="7dp"/>
    </shape>   
 </item>

 <item android:state_pressed="false" >
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <corners 
    android:radius="7dp"
    />
    </shape>
 </item> 

</selector>
```

Comment: Just to point out that I have found that this may not work properly depending on what parent style you are using. In my case, using `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`didn't work but `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton` it did work

Answer (score 2):

What I did was defined the shape and specify the dp of each corner.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="90dp">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<padding />
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>

</shape>
```

If you increase the dp in each corner it will make the button more rounded.

Comment: Have you tried using a style? You may want to create one for a button and then apply it to the which ever buttons. I haven't tried it for buttons before but I know you can add selectors and alter different aspects of a view (height, color, it's selector, images, etc) using a style.

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful at doing exactly what you're describing.  I did the following:

First, I created a new class that extends Button.  In this class, I created a method called setState():

```
public void setState (int s)
{
    if (s > 0 && s < 4 &&)
    {
        this.state = s;
        switch (state)
        {
            case 1:
                setBackgroundDrawable (def_gray);
                break;

            case 2:
                setBackgroundDrawable (lt_gray);
                break;

            case 3:
                setBackgroundDrawable (black);
        }
    }
}
```

The three background drawables you see above are XML files describing the button look.  They are mostly the same, but vary in the color set for each one.  The default gray button is described like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape>

            <gradient
                android:startColor="#333333"
                android:endColor="#333333" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />

            <padding
                android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp" />

        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

As far as I know, that XML format is expecting to be used to configure a color gradient on the button face.  Since that wasn't what I wanted, I set both color values the same and the background color is consistent.  You may need to experiment a bit with color values, but it looks like you've already got a handle on that.