# How to programmatically change button color after set android:background to make it rounded corner?

Tags: android-layout

I've 6 button in my layout. All of it were using custom xml to make it rounded corner in `android:background` using single xml file. But now, how do I change the colour of every button programmatically? Since the `android:background` has been used.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code.

1.Create a xml file in your drawable folder like mybutton.xml and paste the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
         <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
         <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>  
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
         <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

2.Now use this drawable for the background of your view. If the view is button then something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Buttons" />
```

And for colour change use style

Comment: i try using style `<style name="btnFashionStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@color/btn_fashion</item>
    </style>` but wont work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427107/how-to-set-button-selection-color-along-with-rounded-corners-in-android Try this link

Comment: Can we programmatically change the backgroundColor of these buttons? @SummitPathak

Comment: @inverted_index follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842447/android-set-button-background-programmatically

Comment: @SumitPathak how about corners? I want to give rounded corners to a button dynamically. The button itself is generated on the fly