# Add Rounded corners to StateSelected Background of TextView using XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-drawable

I have `RecyclerView` which holds some `TextView`s. I have set background of the `RecyclerView` to the following `recycler_view_background.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius"/>
    <stroke android:color="#D3D3D3" android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

And it works fine, I get rounded corners on my `RecyclerView`.

Here's the catch, when I try to add a background selector to any one of the `TextViews` they don't show rounded corners. Here's the background `xml` for each item `category_item_selector.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/controlbar_gradient">
        <shape>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius"/>
            <stroke android:color="#D3D3D3" android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I am programmatically setting `TextView`'s selected to true in my `RecyclerView.Adapter.ViewHolder`'s `OnClickListener` (Selector is working fine or else I wouldn't have reddish background to the selected item).

Here are the snippets from the application.

[image]
[image]

`RecyclerView` has rounded corners but `TextView`'s background is drawing over it. So when the selected `View` is on Top or Bottom.

Rounded corners are no longer visible even though it shouldn't when I have added rounded corners on selected views.

I keep getting similar solutions when searching for this. And mine is correct according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427107/how-to-set-button-selection-color-along-with-rounded-corners-in-android).

Comment: this selector will not work, because it has only one state (you need a default too) and you have just defined the drawable for this. The inner shape  will be ignored.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I don't need rounded corners for state_selected="false". So it works fine on that level. As for already defined drawable, please check my answer where I have pointed out my own mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while posting this question here. I revised and found my mistake. So here it is.

In my category_item_selector.xml I had set background to `@drawable/controlbar_gradient` which was defined as

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient

        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#7e0809"
        android:endColor=  "#fa0000" />

</shape>
```

And later again in my category_item_selector.xml I was again adding `shape`. So the compiler took the first `shape` it found and rendered that. So all I had to do was change `category_item_selector.xml` to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient

                android:angle="90"
                android:type="linear"
                android:startColor="#7e0809"
                android:endColor=  "#fa0000" />

            <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/player_category_radius"/>
            <stroke android:color="#D3D3D3" android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have also another way to do that...

after set a background for your RecyclerView s**et background to your RecyclerView** items

like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_most_trending"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/recyclerView_background"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**set background to RecyclerView item**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/recyclerView_item_bg">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:padding="10dp"
      />
 </LinearLayout>
```