# How to add background and text color state with rounded corners to implement shine animation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

I was using a CardView as :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardRoot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    card_view:contentPaddingLeft="15dp"
    card_view:contentPaddingRight="15dp"
    >
<Text...>
    />
```

And on my adapter I was doing this manually when clicking

```
private fun updateStyle(isSelected: Boolean) {
            if (isSelected) {
                binding.title.setTextColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        binding.root.context,
                        R.color.blue,
                    ),
                )
                binding.cardRoot.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        binding.root.context,
                        R.color.blue_disabled,
                    ),
                )
            } else {
                binding.title.setTextColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        binding.root.context,
                        R.color.dark_grey,
                    ),
                )
                binding.cardRoot.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        binding.root.context,
                        R.color.grey,
                    ),
                )
            }
        }
```

It was working perfectly, but now I need to add a [`ShineAnimation`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-shine-effect-in-android/) and I need to create this `View` to animate it as it is, but when trying to add the corners to a `Button` or whatever `View` I add it overlaps with the background, so I've tried the state like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446491/4385913) but I'm not success, how could I make it work as it was with a different view (or if possible to remain the `CardView` even better) and add this `shine view`

Comment: ScreenShot will help to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new XML drawable resource (e.g., background_with_states.xml) to define the background and text color states for your CardView. You can use a  to specify different backgrounds and text colors based on the view's state (pressed, focused, etc.). Here's an example:
xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:id="@android:id/background">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/blue_disabled" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:id="@android:id/background">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This XML defines two states: one when the CardView is selected (e.g., clicked), and one for the default state.

In your layout XML, wrap your CardView with a FrameLayout or another layout that can contain multiple child views:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardRoot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:contentPaddingLeft="15dp"
        app:contentPaddingRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_states">

        <!-- Your CardView contents, including the TextView -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            ... />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Add your ShineView here as a child view of the FrameLayout -->

</FrameLayout>
```

In your adapter code, you can set the isSelected state of the CardView and TextView. When the CardView is selected, it will use the background and text color specified in the selector XML. You can use setSelected() on the CardView to change its state.

To add the ShineView, create a custom view or use a library like "Shimmer" to implement the shine animation effect. Place the ShineView as a child of the FrameLayout, and position it over the CardView to create the shine effect.